# Can I enable Safari Reader (desktop) for webpages when icon is not available?

Tags: safari

I'm trying to print to PDF webpages from SQLAlchemy docs.

This page offers the icon:
`https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html`

However additional pages don't have the icon:
 `https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html`

Since the first page loads, I don't expect the site is "blocking" reader view.

Internet search suggests I can turn on Reader (Safari Preferences > Websites > Reader) options on a domain basis, but this setting has no apparent effect.

On Firefox you can rewrite the url to force reader-view, `about:reader?url=`.

Is there a similar workaround for Safari?

Comment: did you try in Safari preferences ... If you want, you can enable Safari Reader Mode on all websites at the bottom of this preferences screen. Just change the When visiting other websites option to On.

Comment: Yes. I tried that (i've edited the post to make this clearer). The first page loads automatically, but the other pages from the same domain do not.

Comment: You can't force Reader in Safari. According to Safari help, "the (Reader) button appears only if the webpage has an article that Reader can show.". If Safari doesn't display the button, that page is formatted in a way Reader can't show and needs to be modified (see for example https://medium.com/@mandy.michael/building-websites-for-safari-reader-mode-and-other-reading-apps-1562913c86c9 for a blog post that discusses building websites for Safari Reader mode).